# Cannot expand asterisk without proper permission

Tags: shell, permissions, sudo, wildcards

Can someone explain to me the following?

```
$ ls -ld /temp/sit/build/
dr-xr-s--- 3 asdf qwer 4096 Jan 31  2012 /temp/sit/build/

$ ls -ld /temp/sit/build/*
ls: /temp/sit/build/*: Permission denied
```

So apprently, I can't use the asterisk here. I've tried it with a sudo command and I get a "no such file" error rather than "permission denied"...

```
sudo ls -l /temp/sit/build/*
ls: /temp/sit/build/batch*: No such file or directory
```

but it finally works if I don't use the *

```
sudo ls -l /temp/sit/build/
total 4
dr-xr-s--- 11 asdf qwer 4096 Oct  3 23:31 file
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The shell that's doing the expansion of the `*` wildcard is the shell where you type it. If the shell has the permission to read the list of files in the directory, then it expands `/temp/sit/build/*` to `/temp/sit/build/file`, and runs `sudo` with the arguments `ls`, `-l` and `/temp/sit/build/file`. If the shell is unable to find any match for `/temp/sit/build/*` (whether it's because there are no matches, or because the shell has no permission to see the matches), then it leaves the pattern alone, and `sudo` is called with the arguments `ls`, `-l` and `/temp/sit/build/*`.

Since there is no file called `/temp/sit/build/*`, the `ls` command complains if you pass it that name. Recall that `ls` doesn't expand wildcards, that's the shell's job.

If you want wildcard expansion to happen in a directory where you don't have read permission, then the expansion must happen in a shell that's started by `sudo` instead of in the shell that calls `sudo`. `sudo` doesn't automatically start a shell, you need to do that explicitly.

```
sudo sh -c 'ls -l /temp/sit/build/*'
```

Here, of course, you can do `sudo ls -l /temp/sit/build/` instead, but that doesn't generalize to other patterns.

Answer (score 2):

In some rare cases you need to double check that you have not disabled globbing for your shell which could give you `No such file or directory` when attempting to list files with wildcard (`*`).

For example:

```
$ ls /tmp/sit/build/*
/tmp/sit/build/file
$ set -f
$ ls /tmp/sit/build/*
ls: cannot access /tmp/sit/build/*: No such file or directory
$ set +f
$ ls /tmp/sit/build/*
/tmp/sit/build/file
```

Check `help set` for more info.